# Linkedlist and jFrames

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have made a queue linkedlist, my main `jFrame` window is called "UI" on which there is a button "Donate" after pressing it a new `jFrame` window called "Donate" opens setting `Visibility` of previous `jFrame(UI)` to `false` (`setVisible(false)`).
`jFrame` "Donate" contains some text field and a "Donate Blood" button in the end, after filling out the text fields we need to press the "Donate Blood" button so that the entered values in text field should be stored in `linkedlist` and then setting `jFrame` "Donate" `Visibility` to `false` and `jFrame` "UI" to true to return back to our main `jFrame` window.
The problem is that every time I click "Confirm Donate" my data is not linking, for e.g: 3 people donated

- John
- Matt
- Harry

When I traverse it I can only see the last entered name, where did `John` and `Matt` disappear to?

Donate button in "UI" action listener code:

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        Donate d = new Donate();
        this.setVisible(false);
        d.setTitle("Donate - Blood Bank");
        d.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Donate Blood button action listener code which calls to donate `jFrame` window:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        UserInterface ui = new UserInterface();
            BloodBank bb = new BloodBank();
            enQueue(jTextField1.getText(), (int)jSpinner1.getValue(), (String)jComboBox1.getSelectedItem(), (String)jComboBox2.getSelectedItem());
            first.Display();
            this.setVisible(false);
            ui.setTitle("Blood Bank");
            ui.setVisible(true);
        }
```

After debugging it many times I found out that if I remove this line of code from the button action listener and stop the `jFrame` "Donate" window from going invisible my queue linked list works fine, is `setVisible(false)` discarding my previous save data? And how can i fix this?

```
this.setVisible(false);
```

To help better understand here are some screenshots:-

Donate button in "UI" jFrame:

[image]

"Donate" `jFrame` window:

[image]

Comment: You are better off using a modal `JDialog` for the pop-up window. It's easier both for you and for the users. As for the list entries, I don't see any related code so it's hard to tell. I suggest you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Be sure to copy-paste your code to a *new project* and make sure it compiles and runs before posting it here.

Comment: Where is the actual code which handles record insertion??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you are creating a new instance of `Donate` in the first actionlistener and that of `UserInterface` in the second actionlistener. If your list is related to the instances of these frames, then you are loosing them. Also, it is not and advisable thing to do. You could create the instances of both the frames in some way so that it can be accessed from both the actionlisteners and then just call `setVisible()` on the same instances. This should solve your problem.